# Unable to get snmptrap working with logstash

Tags: logstash, snmp

I am trying to get the snmptrap input working with logstash.  I am starting logstash as root initially because I want to make sure this works before changing ports.  I am also using the local computer for SNMP because I thought that world be easier to start.  When I use port 161 I get the “SNMP Trap listener died” error.  If I change to port 162 I get no error, but no data.   If I point to a server that does not exist I also get the SNMP Trap listener died error on any port.  I believe it should be port 161, but I may be wrong.

Logstash works if I use a different input.  I eventually want the output to go to graphite and that works too with different input.

Do I have something misconfigured?  Is there some permission thing that could be causing a problem even though I am running as root and everything is on the same machine?

Thanks for any help.

**This is my .conf file:**

```
input {
snmptrap {
 host => "127.0.0.1"
 community => "public"
 port => "161"
 type => "snmp_trap"
  }
}
output {
 stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

**This is the partial result of snmpwalk locally:**

```
snmpwalk -mAll -v1 -cpublic 127.0.0.1:161
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.2.0 = OID: iso.3.6.1.4.1.8072.3.2.10
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0 = Timeticks: (7218152) 20:03:01.52
```

**This is netstat:**

```
root@lab-graphite:~# netstat -lpn | grep snmp
udp   0   0  127.0.0.1:161     0.0.0.0:*       43559/snmpd
udp   0   0  0.0.0.0:54155     0.0.0.0:*       43559/snmpd
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     2593117  43559/snmpd         /var/agentx/master
```

**This is the full error message:**

```
SNMP Trap listener died {:exception=>#<SocketError: bind: name or service not known>, :backtrace=>["org/jruby/ext/socket/RubyUDPSocket.java:160:in `bind'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/snmp-1.2.0/lib/snmp/manager.rb:540:in `initialize'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/snmp-1.2.0/lib/snmp/manager.rb:585:in `create_transport'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/snmp-1.2.0/lib/snmp/manager.rb:618:in `initialize'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-input-snmptrap-2.0.4/lib/logstash/inputs/snmptrap.rb:74:in `build_trap_listener'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-input-snmptrap-2.0.4/lib/logstash/inputs/snmptrap.rb:78:in `snmptrap_listener'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-input-snmptrap-2.0.4/lib/logstash/inputs/snmptrap.rb:53:in `run'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.3.2-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:342:in `inputworker'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.3.2-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:336:in `start_input'"], :level=>:warn}
```

Comment: FYI. The default port for SNMP traps is 162/UDP. It won't be listening on your remote machine. You may want to bind the host in your configuration to its actual physical address and not the loopback.

Comment: I have used the name, the local IP address and the loopback without success.  I think I am going to configure a simple remote snmp server on the same network.  Trying to read the local snmp server may be causing a problem.

Answer (score 0):

In .conf file "host" parameter stands for ip address or hostname of computer running logstash. If you are going to receive snmp traps from external world sources it should not be localhost (127.0.0.1). It is OK for local setup tests though.

As already mentioned in comment, default snmptrap port is 162 (and there is no reason to change it in your setup).
Also, since netstat shows that there is snmpd running and it listens to udp port 161, your logstash won't be allowed to bind to the same port 161.

```
`snmpwalk` is not the right way to test your setup (it actually polls snmpd daemon on port 161) - it is `snmptrap` command that will send trap to your logstash input. For example,

`snmptrap -v1 -c public 127.0.0.1 .1.3 i 0 123456780 127.0.0.1 0 .1.3.6 i 12345`
```

You can also run `tcpdump port 162` as root to check that `snmptrap` is sending packets to target at 127.0.0.1:162 .

(here 127.0.0.1 is the host address used in logstash .conf below).

So, for local test use

```
`snmptrap {
 host => "127.0.0.1"
 community => "public"
 port => "162"
 type => "snmp_trap"
  }
}`
```

Comment: I believe the problem is that this is an snmptrap input plugin (as the documentation indicates).  I assume that the only messages that are captured are the traps that are sent from the snmp server of which there were none.  So it was working all along☺  What I am looking for is a way to regularly query snmp using logstash and send it to the graphite output plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the SNMPTRAP input, but expecting it to work like a regular SNMP get.  It was actually working, but no traps were being sent.